# Reuse an apollo graphql query definition for multiple vue properties

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

In my vue screen I'd like to use one apollo graphql I've defined for two properties. As far as I understand the name of the property must match a name of the attribute in the returned json structure. 
I naivly tried to use the queries for two properties but it throws an error for the second one.

```js
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      userId: number,
      user: null as User | null,
      previousUserId: number,
      previousUser: null as User | null
    };
  },
  ...
  apollo {
    user: {
      query: READ_ONE_USER,
      variables() {
        return {
          userId: this.userId
        };
      }
    },
    previousUser: {
      query: READ_ONE_USER,
      variables() {
        return {
          userId: this.previousUserId
        };
      },
```

```js
export const READ_ONE_USER = gql(`
query user($userId: Int!) { user(userId: $userId)
  {
    id
    firstName
    lastName
    email
  }
}
`);
```

I expected no problems but I get "Missing previousUser attribute on result {user: ...}"

Answer (score 2):

Daniel's solution didn't work out for me, I still got the same error message.

But there's another way to do it, you can provide an `update` function to tell apollo how to extract the result out of the data read from the server:

```
  apollo {
    user: {
      query: READ_ONE_USER,
      variables() {
        return {
          userId: this.userId
        };
      }
    },
    previousUser: {
      query: READ_ONE_USER,
      variables() {
        return {
          userId: this.previousUserId
        };
      },
      update(data) {
        return data.user;
      }
    }
```

This is documented at https://github.com/vuejs/vue-apollo/blob/v4/packages/docs/src/api/smart-query.md#options

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Can confirm this is working.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the docs, you can manually add smart queries inside the `created` hook:

```
created () {
  this.$apollo.addSmartQuery('user', {
    query: READ_ONE_USER,
    variables() {
      return {
        userId: this.userId
      };
    },
  })
  this.$apollo.addSmartQuery('previousUser', {
    query: READ_ONE_USER,
    variables() {
      return {
        userId: this.previousUserId
      };
    },
  })
}
```